# Вопрос по Smarty PHP

Tags: php, smarty, шаблонизаторы

Как реализовать данный код на smarty? Конкретно, как вставить `$userPerm->getUserPerm($DBquery) == 'post_comment'` в условие smarty на странице *.tpl

```
<?if($userPerm->getUserPerm($DBquery) == 'post_comment'):?>
что-то вывести
<?endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решил проблему.

**Это код в файле *.tpl**

```
{foreach from = $getAllPerm item = perm}
    <div class='group-form'>
        {if $userPerm->getUserPerm($perm.perm_key)}                     
            <div class='col-lg-6'><span class='name-form'>{$perm.perm_name}</span></div>
            <div class='col-lg-6 text-form' ><input type='text' name='link_name' value='Разрешено'></div>
        {else}
            <div class='col-lg-6'><span class='name-form'>{$perm.perm_name}</span></div>
            <div class='col-lg-6 text-form' ><input type='text' name='link_name' value='Запрещено'></div>
        {/if}
    </div>
{/foreach}
```

**В файле обработчике (*.php), делаем следующее:**

```
$getAllPerm = $userPerm->getAllPerm($DBQuery);
$smarty->assign('getAllPerm', $getAllPerm);                 
$smarty->assign('userPerm', $userPerm);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{if $userPerm->getUserPerm($DBquery) == 'post_comment'}
   Текст..
{/if}
```

Comment: Делал так, выдает ошибку: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getUserPerm() on a non-object in I:\home\site.loc\www\engine\libs\sysplugins\smarty_internal_templatebase.php(171) : eval()'d code on line 145`

Comment: @dikardRus, так вы как `userPerm` объявляете? Вы бы сам шаблон еще привели. К тому же - `DBquery` тогда в шаблон вставить надо. Вот только - зачем? Может вынести эти проверки из шаблона? Т.е. где-то вне шаблона получаете результат, а в шаблоне просто на основе этого результата вывод делаете?

Answer (score 0):

Шаблоны не должны заниматься генерацией данных. Ваш код должен обрабатывать контроллер. А в smarty должно остаться только что-то типа
{if $userPerm == 'post_comment'}
что-то вывести
{/if}
smarty надо использовать в MVC